# How do I provide API client so it has access to auth provider state?

Tags: reactjs

I am working in a project that handles showing authenticated/non-authenticated components by setting a state variable in the auth provider.

```
function App() {
  const { user, loading } = useAuth();

  if (loading) {
    return <LoadPanel visible={true} />;
  }

  if (user) {
    return <Content />;
  }

  return <UnauthenticatedContent />;
}

export default function Root() {
  const screenSizeClass = useScreenSizeClass();



  return (
    <Router history={customHistory}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <NavigationProvider>
          <div className={`app ${screenSizeClass}`}>
            <App />
          </div>
        </NavigationProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
  );
```

So if `user` is set to null then the behaviour is that user is logged out.

The user is stored inside the auth context like so

```
function AuthProvider(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  
  ///...
  
 }
```

This causes me some problems as sometimes cookies get cleared or a session times out.  The API client I am using allows for a method that gets triggered when the client gets a 401 status on a request.  I want to set the auth user to null inside this method but I do not know how to call into the auth context from the client which I am declaring in global scope like this:

```
let _client = new JsonServiceClient(environment.apiUrl);
_client.onAuthenticationRequired = () => {

  //how do I clear the auth provider user state from here?
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true))
};

export let client = _client;
```

My thoughts are that I probably shouldn't be exposing the client on the global scope and I should be providing it inside the context somewhere but I can't quite get my head around how to structure this.  All API requests go through this client.

Can someone point me in right direction for how to get this client working right with the way the auth works in this app I am working on please?

Comment: I don't know how complex your app is, but there is a good "recipe" here that you can follow or tweak for your use-case: https://usehooks.com/useAuth/. I sometimes use it myself on simpler projects.

Comment: The template I am using uses almost identical pattern but how do I add the API client to this pattern?

Comment: Just put it inside the `use-auth.js` and have all your exposed API methods returned from the hook as an object just like the firebase one in the recipe. From there, wherever you use `const auth = useAuth()`, you can access the methods like `auth.clearUser()` and it should automatically rerender.